# CSS change px to %

Tags: css

I'm currently using pixels at my CSS, and I would like to know if there is an auto calculator or an easier way to change this values to percents not by changing elements one by one...

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: If you know your target screen size, or minimum. then you can do something like. ItemSize(height)/screenSize(height) *100. You will need to do this for height and width. So, automatically no, calculated yes.

Comment: Percents are calculated from the size of elements parent. So it starts from the size of the browser window. So its dynamic value. but pixel values are static. So you have to use javascript to calulate those value for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind a little javascript

```
function getWidth(elem) {
    if(!elem.parentNode) return 100;
    return 100*elem.offsetWidth/elem.parentNode.offsetWidth;
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9GHR/1/)

Comment: Inspired by Thomas Harris' and Abel Raj's comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use jQuery or other plugins to automatically do that.

Or you need to first group the elements and change their properties. Such a

```
a {
  /* property: value; */
}
```

Then, you can manage them. But remember, that once you change them, they won't be applied to each of the element by themself. You'll still need to change the properties for each one after the other.